# How to implement a stack of integers in array in Java Collection Framework as a variable-size array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, array-algorithms

The question is how to implement a stack of integers in an array in Java Collection Framework as a variable-size array?

Comment: Can you give more details on your request ? do you need to implement a LIFO data structure ? if yes, it already exist by default in java ...

Comment: I suggest you read how `Stack` in the JDK is implemented as it does this (except for references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stack of Integer boxed objects suites for you then you can just use java.util.Stack implementation from Java Collections.
But if your requirement is to use only primitive types take a look at java.util.Stack [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Stack.java). All you need to do to make it work with primitive integer is just replace type of base array and all method parameters and return values. It's simple.

Third option is to use one of 3d party collection libraries, for example [goldmnan sachs collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections) if I remember right. They provide such solution already.

Comment: The GS Collections library is now an Eclipse project: https://projects.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-collections https://www.eclipse.org/collections/

Comment: Also, in the core JDK, `java.util.ArrayDeque` is a better stack than `java.util.Stack`.